# Unknown Recursive Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have found the answer to this problem a while ago but have since forgotten it. After hours of searching again, I cannot seem to find it. I have this recursive method:

```
public static int f(int x, int y) {
    if (x==0) return 1+y;
    if (y==0) return f(x-1,1);
    return f(x-1, f(x,y-1));
}
```

I know that the formula for determining what will return is:

when `x = 0`, the formula is `y + 1`
when `x = 1`, the formula is `y + 2` 
when `x = 2`, the formula is `2y + 3`.

I don't know anything beyond that.

My question(s) is what is this recursive algorithm called and is there a way to determine a completely simplified function for any value of `x` and `y`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ackermann function....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like the Ackermann function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function

According to wikipedia this is a multiply recursive problem so I think there is no non-recursive way to represent it.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you, and such a fast response! Will accept whenever it will let me.